# Use NumPy array as key in Numba TypedDict

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to modify a class to use Numba's `@jitclass`, and part of this class needs to map NumPy arrays to int values using a dictionary. I had been using the `tobytes` method of the arrays as a key, but this method is not supported within Numba. Is there any Numba compatible way to key a dictionary with NumPy arrays? The string method for arrays also seems to be unsupported within Numba.

Comment: Show us the code you tried which Numba rejects.

Comment: I don't really have relevant code to post that tells more than the original post unfortunately, at a bit of a loss on things to try

Answer (score 0):

If your NumPy arrays don't change memory addresses, you could make a key based on pointers to their memory address. Note that this would only be applicable if the array are to be modified in-place:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(3)
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> ptr, _ = arr.__array_interface__['data']
>>> ptr
140556718588416
>>> dct = {ptr: arr}
>>> dct[ptr]
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> arr += 10
>>> dct[ptr]
array([10, 11, 12])
>>> arr[...] = 0
>>> dct[ptr]
array([0, 0, 0])
```

But if you actually change the memory location of the array, you'll run into bugs:

```py
>>> arr = np.ones_like(arr)
>>> arr
array([1, 1, 1])
>>> dct[ptr] # oops!
array([0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without that much information to go on, I would suggest to first map your arrays to an intermediate dictionary like so:

```
list_of_arrays = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
intermediate_dict = {x:y for x,y in enumerate(list_of_arrays)}
```

and then after you're done combine this disctionary with the resulting dictionary to get the information that you need.